# C++ How can I move or swap pair<const T, U>?

Tags: c++, data-structures, design-patterns

I'm writing a B-Tree class. I want to support for all four cases like `std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::map`, `std::multimap`.

I verified that my code works correctly for first two cases. The problem is the latter two.
Their declarations are like this:

```
template <typename T>
concept Containable = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, T>;

using index_t = std::ptrdiff_t;

template <Containable K, index_t t = 2, typename Comp = std::ranges::less,
          typename Alloc = std::allocator<K>>
using BTreeSet = detail::BTreeBase<K, K, t, Comp, false, Alloc>;

template <Containable K, index_t t = 2, typename Comp = std::ranges::less,
          typename Alloc = std::allocator<K>>
using BTreeMultiSet = detail::BTreeBase<K, K, t, Comp, true, Alloc>;

template <Containable K, Containable V, index_t t = 2,
          typename Comp = std::ranges::less,
          typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const K, V>>>
using BTreeMap = detail::BTreeBase<K, std::pair<const K, V>, t, Comp, false, Alloc>;

template <Containable K, Containable V, index_t t = 2,
          typename Comp = std::ranges::less,
          typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const K, V>>>
using BTreeMultiMap =
    detail::BTreeBase<K, std::pair<const K, V>, t, Comp, true, Alloc>;
```

`BTreeBase` is like this

```
template <Containable K, typename V, index_t t, typename Comp, bool AllowDup,
          typename Alloc>
requires(t >= 2) class BTreeBase {

// ... details ...
};
```

For `BTreeMap` the `value_type` is `std::pair<const K, V>`. For associative containers, changing keys via dereferencing iterators is unacceptable.

This line gives me a headache:

```
x->keys_[i] = std::move(y->keys_[t - 1]);
```

It doesn't compile. `std::iter_swap` or `std::swap` don't work

Here `x` and `y` are `BTreeBase::Node` and `keys_` is `std::vector<value_type, Alloc>`.

Standard library containers `std::map`, `std::unordered_map` uses the same approach but they don't have this problem, because it is based on red-black trees and hash tables, so a node has exactly single key, so you can just move a node, not a key.

But B-Tree is a different beast. A node has many keys, and moving or swapping keys between nodes should be possible. (user still should not be allowed to change key from outside)

How can I deal with this?

Comment: You could destroy an element (via `Alloc::destroy`) then copy-construct in the now-empty space (via `Alloc::construct`). This would be difficult to make exception-safe.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If I want to allow copy then it would be much simple, I can just ```x->keys_[i] = y->keys_[t - 1];``` I want to allow keys like ```std::string```, where copies are expensive, so the solution is "possible" but undesirable

Comment: That assignment won't in fact compile.

Comment: Ugh, you're right... I'm thinking how to move the pair object

Comment: Could your implementation move around pointers or indexes to those pairs, rather than pairs themselves?

Comment: Also, be aware that `std::vector<value_type>` is going to copy all the elements every time it needs to reallocate; since it can't move them for the same reason you can't.

Comment: That's a very good catch, but I think I made a safeguard for that, constructor of ```Node``` always do ```keys_.reserve(2 * t - 1)``` and a node of B-Tree can never have keys more than 2 * t - 1

Comment: Note that `std::map::insert`, say, doesn't invalidate any iterators, pointers or references to existing elements. The implementation you envision probably won't be able to guarantee that. See if that's a problem.

Comment: That's inevitable, that's B-Tree's problem. Anyway, I've found a working code, I'll post it now

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I decided to change my design, just to use ```pair<K, V>``` internally, and convert it to ```pair<const K&, V&>``` just before exposing the iterators to users. I don't know other way, but at least this avoids copy.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is not to use `std::pair<const K, V>`.

This is my changed design:

```
template <typename> struct TreePairRef {};

template <typename T, typename U> struct TreePairRef<std::pair<T, U>> {
  using type = std::pair<const T &, U &>;
};

template <typename TreePair>
using PairRefType = TreePairRef<TreePair>::type;

template <typename> struct TreeRefBase {};

template <typename T, typename U> struct TreeRefBase<std::pair<const T&, U&>> {
  using type = std::pair<T, U>;
};

template <typename TreeRef>
using RefBaseType = typename TreeRefBase<TreeRef>::type;
```

Changed iterator:

```
  template <typename T, bool Const, bool isRef> struct BTreeIterator {
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = std::conditional_t<isRef, RefBaseType<T>, T>;
    using pointer = std::conditional_t<Const, const value_type*, value_type*>;
    using reference = std::conditional_t<Const, const value_type&, std::conditional_t<isRef, T, value_type&>>;
    using node_type = Node *;
    using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
    using iterator_concept = std::iterator_category;
```

Tree type design:

```
// invariant: V is either K or std::pair<const K, Value> for some Value type.
  static constexpr bool is_set_ = std::is_same_v<K, V>;

  using value_type = V;
  using reference_type = std::conditional_t<is_set_, const V &, PairRefType<V>>;
  using iterator_type = BTreeIterator<std::conditional_t<is_set_, value_type, reference_type>, is_set_, !is_set_>;
  using const_iterator_type = BTreeIterator<std::conditional_t<is_set_, value_type, reference_type>, true, !is_set_>;
  using reverse_iterator_type = std::reverse_iterator<std::iterator_type>;
  using const_reverse_iterator_type = std::reverse_iterator<std::const_iterator_type>;
```

This design works without more hacks

```
  namespace fc = frozenca;
  fc::BTreeMap<std::string, int> tree;

  tree["a"] = 3;
  tree["aaaa"] = 4;
  tree["bas"] = 6;
  tree["asdf"] = 6;

  for (const auto& [k, v] : tree) {
    std::cout << k << ' ' << v << '\n';
  }

  tree["asdf"] = 3333;

  std::cout << tree["asdf"] << '\n';
```

Output

```
a 3
aaaa 4
asdf 6
bas 6
3333
```

Comment: Just like `std::shift_right`, `std::rotate` requires that the element type be *MoveAssignable*. But `std::pair<const K, V>` isn't.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I finally found some equilibristics, C++ is too tired..